# Type casts in C and type safety

Tags: c, types, casting, type-safety

In chapter 6.2.1 of Mitchell's book (Concepts in Programming Languages), it mentioned that:

> **Type Casts.** Type casts allow a value of one type to be used as another type. In C in particular, an integer can be cast to a function, allowing a jump to a location that does not contain the correct form of instructions to be a C function.

so I was up to use this non-safety and doing something unusual
I tried something like this (pseudo-code):

```
int x = 0;
print "loop";
x();
```

to create an infinite loop. I tried by changing and testing, but I couldn't cope with that.
How can I do something or everything else like these stuffs?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it compile? If the answer is "no", I suggest you burn the book.

Comment: There's no standard-conforming way of converting object pointers to function pointers. However, there may be platform-specific ways of populating a function pointer with a particular value.

Comment: Even if you managed to get the address of that point in the code into a variable, and cast that to a function, and then called it, it wouldn't be an infinite loop, so much as infinite recursion. Which would just fill the stack up and crash anyway.

Comment: @wildplasser this is my own code and it has compile error but the quote is from the book, and I think it is one of the most known books in the field.

Comment: @JasonD I don't get it, can you explain more?

Comment: You are attempting to have a function call itself. This is called recursion. And as you have no condition on which this recursion stops, it is infinite. And that won't work, because when you call a function, the return address (at least) is pushed onto the stack, which is a finite resource. Eventually it will fill up, and crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Soroush, here's an example that might help you better understand what's going on behind the scenes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("begin\n");
    printf("loop\n");

    // declare a function pointer
    int (*loopPtr)();
    // set the function pointer to the current function
    loopPtr = main;
    // skip over the first printf();
    loopPtr += 22;
    // call the new location
    loopPtr();
}
```

For me, it works on x86_64 when compiled with `clang -O0` (well, it works until the stack is exhausted since this is infinite recursion and each function call chews through stack space).

I determined the offset 22 by compiling, then disassembling and subtracting the address of the start of `main()` from the address of the second `printf()`.

First, I compiled it:

```
clang -O0 test.c
```

Then disassembled it:

```
otool -tv a.out
```

...which produced this output:

```
[...]
_main:
0000000100000ee0    pushq   %rbp
0000000100000ee1    movq    %rsp,%rbp
0000000100000ee4    subq    $0x20,%rsp
0000000100000ee8    leaq    0x00000073(%rip),%rdi
0000000100000eef    movb    $0x00,%al
0000000100000ef1    callq   0x100000f40
0000000100000ef6    leaq    0x0000006c(%rip),%rdi
0000000100000efd    movl    %eax,0xf4(%rbp)
0000000100000f00    movb    $0x00,%al
0000000100000f02    callq   0x100000f40
[...]
```

`_main:` indicates the entrypoint of the `main()` function, whose first address is 0x100000ee0.  The first `callq` instruction corresponds with the first `printf()` call, which I want to skip, so I chose the address just after that: 0x100000ef6. 0x100000ef6 minus 0x100000ee0 is 22 decimal.

Answer (score 6):

That's not how it works.

In C you *can* cast an integer value to a function pointer value and then call such a function pointer

```
void (*ptr)() = (void (*)())42;
ptr();
```

but this will probably just result in a crash unless you know exactly what you are doing, i.e. you already know in some way that, at address 42, starts a function with that signature; having a fixed address like in this example may happen in system programming, while it's extremely rare in application programming.

What *actually* happens more often than it would be desirable (especially in Windows programming) is to pass around function pointers casted to some integers (callbacks in `LPARAM`/`WPARAM` anyone?), and then cast them back to function pointers to actually use them.

Also, what happens when such casts/calls are performed is outside the scope of the C standard, that leaves the implementations free to do what they want in this regard.

Comment: Is there any way that I can retrieve current address of my code, by this way it might work...

Comment: You can, though no good will come of it. It certainly won't 'work' for any meaningful definition of 'working'.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `x()` doesn't magically call a function at that address. I think he means something like:

```
typedef void (*functionPtr)();

int x;
//...
functionPtr foo = (functionPtr)x;
//or
functionPtr goo = (functionPtr)&x;
foo();
```

Comment: I *think* he wants to the address of `x` (`&x`) to be assigned to `foo`. Could be wrong though.

Comment: @amit ok, same thing (added though)

Comment: @amit Given that he said that he expected an infinite loop, I'd rather think that he wanted to get the address of the instruction that sets `x` to 0, i.e. he basically wants to `goto` to the line where `x` is set.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore just because I want to have better intuition about compiler, is it so bad??

Answer (score 1):

Your book is misleading. The only thing that is allowed by the standard is the cast operation, and this only if the value fits. Execution of such a function pointer is *undefined behavior* in most cases. You'd have to know your system very well to make that possible. So the second part of your cited paragraph:

> In C in particular, an integer can be cast to a function, allowing a
>   jump to a location that does not contain the correct form of
>   instructions to be a C function.

is just not true in that form. In particular all decent modern systems don't allow you to execute data, you'd have to set special flags for a page such that it can be considered to contain executable code.